# Importing vector lines (SVG) as Curves

Tags: bezier-curves, import, svg

I got the following line drawing in Illustrator.

[image: Vector Lines]

As I export it as SVG and importing it in Blender. Blender automatically creates from the seperate lines closed Curves. 
[image: Imported SVG; closed curves]

How to import a SVG without closing the curves?

Comment: could you please share your svg file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closed curve is called Cyclic, to open and close a Cyclic go into Edit Mode and hit the hotkey Alt+C.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to installing a blender add-on, you might want to give this one a try:  [Blender Add-on to Import Shape Keys](https://youtu.be/XMimQfQR_ss)

It appears to have quite a few import options.